# Eclipse 3.7 C/C++ Code Analysis "codan" flagging bogus errors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 with the C/C++ CDT 8.0.

I configured Eclipse to use my own makefiles and now the code analysis "codan" tool flags errors on otherwise correct code.  I've tried to restore Eclipse's settings, but I'm unable to restore proper behavior.  Errors pile up quickly by simply clicking on a source tab.  The errors make me suspect codan is ignoring most of the #include files in my C++ files.

Can I see and configure the codan tool command line invoked by Eclipse?  If not, any ideas on how I can debug this problem would be appreciated.

I found the Preferences->Code Analysis dialog, but that doesn't specify how Eclipse invokes the tool.

Comment: +1 I don't know why I didn't think to ask this here! I use makefiles managed by eclipse and it still flags all my included classes.

Comment: Check your indexer preferences. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095295/why-cant-codan-find-size-t/10095683#10095683

Answer (score 1):

You need to add include paths of Standard Library headers in [Paths and Symbols -> Includes](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm) tab, if you have not done it yet. Then refresh whole project and Standard Library symbols should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, but all my paths are already setup.  When I let Eclipse build the project, there are no missing paths.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Maybe rebuild Index and restart Eclipse?